# Using Browse function input to open_woorkbook

Tags: tkinter, xlrd

Hei

I'm new too python and programing.
I'm writing a program where i want users to browse for a excel file and then the program does som calculations based on the information. I got most of the code working, but cant get this part working:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
from xlrd import open_workbook
import Tkinter as tk

def file():
   file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(initialdir="C:",title="Choose a file")

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root,text="browse",command=file)
book=open_workbook(file)
```

I think my problem is in the (file) part, how should i write this?

This is the error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Patrick/Desktop/Python/Python 2.7/Bonusutregning filer/Bonusutregning GUI v.3", line 12, in 
    book=open_workbook(file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd__init__.py", line 425, in open_workbook
    on_demand=on_demand,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd__init__.py", line 878, in biff2_8_load
    f = open(filename, open_mode)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, function found

Answer (score 0):

I think this line has an error. Try changing to

```
file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent = root,title="Choose a file")
```

This should work